# jQuery Replace Element Content

Tags: jquery, function, replace

I am trying to replace the content of a `<td>` element when it exactly matches a string. My code does not seem to work, can anyone please say what I might be doing wrong?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("td").click(function(){
            if (Matches(this, "1")
                ReplaceCellContent(this,"A");
        });
    });

    <!-- Replaces an HTML inner value [find] with a new value [replace] -->
    function ReplaceCellContent(element, replace) {
        $(.element).html(replace);
    }

    <!-- Returns true if [element] contains [stringToMatch] -->
    function Matches(element, stringToMatch) {
        return $(element).text() === stringToMatch;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hopefully you didn't use HTML comments in javascript? And you have syntax errors, open the console.

Comment: Yes, I did.. I have changed the comments to javascript style and the console prints `Unexpected identifier` with line 5, which calls the `ReplaceCellContent` function. Unfortunately I can't see what is wrong with it.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis, and there are more syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks I had difficulty spotting that, I am used to using Eclipse but have started using Notepad++ for Javascript. Is there perhaps an IDE for JavaScript that will show syntax errors that you can recommend?

Comment: @Adamme You might wanna look at [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) for web development. Plugin developed by users are very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Karl-Andre, will be trying it out :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$(element).text()` return the text including new line character and tabulation.

Try to trim that value :

```
return $.trim($(element).text()) === stringToMatch;
```

---

You are missing a closing parenthesis :

```
if (Matches(this, "1"))
```

Comment: I tried the trim function but it doesn't make a difference. The error is with the `ReplaceCellContent` function, but I am not sure what why.

Comment: Yeah, a missing parenthesis.